# Выбор предлога в сочетании со словом "квитанция"

Tags: предлоги

Как верно: квитанция за капремонт (газ, воду, жилищные услуги и т. д.) или на капремонт? Тот же вопрос к слову платежка - платежка на капремонт или за капремонт? Спасибо всем откликнувшимся!

Answer (score 1):

Обычно применяется форма "платить (за что?) за газ, воду, капремонт", то есть за услуги. Вообще говоря,  платить можно **чем, кому и за что**.

Также квитанция  за "газ, воду, капремонт" (разг.) Это документ,  подтверждающий факт получения денег **за** услуги.

Целевой предлог НА используется  сочетаниях "платить взносы на капремонт" или "взносы на капремонт".